# Converting longtext to mediumtext in Wordpress wp_postmeta table

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, performance

following recommendations to increase performance of my wp_postmeta table, I converted my meta_type field type to varchar 191, hoping this would reduce also the table size (which did not happen). I have a 1 GB wp_postmeta table - the size causes problems with backups, update operations etc. The table is bloated because of my variations which is of course the root of the problem which I cannot solve. So I thought about converting the meta_value longtext type to mediumtext. In my staging environment, postmeta shrank to 400 mb. Did anybody do such thing already? Is the recommended or too criticial? Thanks for help. Frank

Comment: I don't imagine changing the column type would help. It'll just be a different mechanism for storing the same amount of data, or worst case truncating data you've already got which will probably break something.

Comment: What data gets stored for variations exactly? I can't see how you'd get up to 1GB. However this is probably a question for somewhere WooCommerce-specific, e.g. try the WooCommerce support routes or https://developer.woo.com